# Align images responsive in a flower shape

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have 4 icons which should align like the image below.

I've tried to first put them into a `<div>` with a class which controlls the position.
Now with my knowledge I would give every each image a absolute position, but that will not work, because on every res. my images are not together and just all over the place.
How can I align my images like a "flower" in a responsive way.

[image: Image Container]

Comment: Please read [ask] and post [mcve]

Comment: in relation to 4 icons i would create 3 a flex div with 3 columns and center the content vertical

Comment: Absolute positioning - in this case the wrong solution to the problem, as it will only look good on one screen

Comment: I have a similair issue

Comment: Look into CSS grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a responsive layout you can use CSS grid:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  width: 50vw;
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
}

.container>div {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container>div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}

.container>div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.container>div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}

.container>div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Obviously set the container width to what you require.

This snippet sets the divs in a clockwise fashion starting at the left most div.

Comment: That is a really nice responsive one. Thank m8.

Answer (score 1):

I have just recreated what you posted above. I can help you when you specify what you really need

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  height:100%;
  align-items:center
}
.sec{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border:1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sec"></div>
  <div class="sec2">
    <div class="sec"></div>
    <div class="sec"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sec"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to create 3 columns wrapped in a flex container and aligned vertically

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  align-items: center;
}
```